# SIM7000E modem stops sending SEND OK reply

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, modem, gprs, simcom

I am using a SIMCOM SIM7000E modem to send data using MQTT. Usually modem reply correctly to
AT+CIPSEND command and sent ">" to enter the required data and then reply with "SEND OK" after entering the data. But I have noticed when running after around 5 or 6 hours modem stops replying with SEND OK, anyway data is received at server side. Have anyone noticed this? Is there a solution for this?

At the moment I have updated the firmware of the modem to 1351B08SIM7000E results are same.

Comment: If you do a hard reset then re-power what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not receiving the acknowledgement to the modem from the server. Using AT+CIPQSEND = 1 modem will just accept data and transmit them and it won't wait for the acknowledgement. Modem will reply with DATA ACCEPT:xx (xx = length of sent data)